# Add main/java classes to my test/java directory in intellij

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I am new to intellij. I am switching from eclispe Kepler.

I do not have a maven project, but I do have a maven directory structure. My classes are in src/main/java with my tests in src/test/java.

My unit tests are complaining because they can't find the classes from src/main/java. What is the proper way to add this to the build path so that my unit tests can find the source?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because adding the junit jar file did not fix this problem.

Comment: Appologies, I should read the question more carefully.

Comment: The directories structures for tests and tested classes must fit. Here is how to do it easily: stackoverflow.com/a/36057080/715269

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Right click the "src/main/java" directory and select "Mark directory
  as > Sources root".
- Right click the "src/test/java" directory and select "Mark directory
  as > Test Sources root"

Also, make sure you use packages underneath your source folders.

Comment: @TheThom ok, are you using packages?

Comment: Yes. Both the original class and the unit test are in the same package, although in different directories.

Comment: Does IntelliJ have any suggestions for what classes that it's indicating are in error in the tests?

Comment: @NickHolt Not sure i follow your question. I'm getting cannot find symbol: class ConnectHistory location ConnectHistoryTest. I'm getting no further advice. I tried using Ctrl+Alt+O to see if it would straighten things out, but no luck.

Comment: Before you compile, if you look at `ConnectHistoryTest` the IDE will highlight the errors - I'd expect to see an error on the import of `ConnectionHistory` and an error where it's used.  If you put the cursor on the point that it's used IntelliJ will suggest a class to import or nothing if there's no obvious choices - does that happen?

Comment: @NickHolt Because they are in the same package, no import is necessary. The error is in the first reference to ConnectHistory. It simply indicates Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: The IDE doesn't seem to think they're in the same package, otherwise it would work.  Are there errors in `ConnectionHistory`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45298/discussion-between-the-thom-and-nick-holt)

Answer (score 5):

Jetbrains directed me to here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html. I added the main/java directory as a module dependency under the test module and everything started working.