# Intellij not finding source files from test directory

Tags: intellij-idea

I am pretty new to Intellij and just started my first Maven project. I have the following directory structure:

```
MyProject
├── myapp.iml
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main (sources root)
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── mysite
    │   │           └── myapp
    │   │               └── App.java
    │   └── main.iml
    └── test (test sources root)
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── mysite
        │           └── myapp
        │               └── AppTest.java
        └── test.iml
```

The problem is that the Intellij compiler can't resolve symbol `App` in `AppTest.java`. In the Project Structure, I have `MyProject` set to the content root for the module `MyProject`, `src/main` set to the content root for the module `main`, and `src/test` set to the project root for the module `test`.

I tried the solution here: [Add main/java classes to my test/java directory in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141521/add-main-java-classes-to-my-test-java-directory-in-intellij) but Intellij wouldn't let me add `src/main` as a dependency of `src/test`. It tells me: Module MyProject must not contain source root "blah/blah/src/main/java". The root already belongs to module "main".

Can someone please advise how to set up my modules/project so that Intellij can find all of the classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to solve this: First, create the test class in the test directory. When you initialize the class to be tested inside testClass, it will show a compiler error. Keep the cursor there and press `ALT+ENTER`, then, from the pop-up menu, select create class. It's done.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not entirely sure why this worked but the exact steps I followed are below.

Comment: (1) Create a new class in the test sources root directory. Doesn't matter what it is. (2) Add an arbitrary method to the new class (the error-finding thing didn't work unless I created a method first). (3) Include the line `App app = new App();` in the method. (4) Hover the mouse over the word `App` until the light-bulb error-finding icon appears. (5) Select it, then select add 'main' project to dependencies. I don't understand why this doesn't work if you try doing it manually.

Comment: Actually i faced the similar issue i sorted it out this way. Might be some intellij problem not quite sure

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I discovered is that Intellij created for `MyProject`, `main`, and `test`. Getting rid of the `main` and `test` modules also seems to solve the problem with no noticeable external side effects. Yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the main module as a dependency of the test module.